# from two tables using single query How to fetch results

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch two different column value from two different tables.first i want to fetch quesion and id  from tbl_question and then the tbl_answers form Fk question_id  is used to fetch the details of that tbl_answers  from tbl_answes and display question_id same two enty and than data whenever tbl_question id 1 and tbl_answer a_id entry pramary key a_id entry two  and than tbl_question id same entry two bar.How to do that from a single query Here is my try

I want like this image view

[tbl_question and tbl_answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54Fxz.png)

[changes view this view drew like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBq0R.png)

this code

```
 sql = SELECT a_id, id, image_name, image, question

 FROM tbl_answers a, tbl_question q

 WHERE q.id = a.question_id
```

Comment: With a `join`. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html This also is only a mysql/SQL question as it stands. If there is a PHP/mysqli issue please post that.

Comment: and what's wrong with your current query?